# iPad image glitch while img revert with jquery-ui draggable

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

When I drag an image on **iPad** with [jQuery-ui Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), I get a small portion of the dragged **image printed on the screen** during the **revert**.

Anyone have an idea why and how to solve this?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cRDMX/1/

**Javascript**

```
var next = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".slider .btn" ).draggable({ 
    revert: function() {
      if(next) {
        $("#container").addClass("active");
        alert("open")
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },
    axis: "x",
    containment: "parent",
    drag: function() {
      var lft = $( ".slider .btn" ).position().left;
      if(lft > 190) {
        next = true;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Environnement:**
iPad 4
iOS 6.1.3

Comment: I already tried to add -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); to the dragged img.

Comment: A minimal, functional example would be great. Hard to troubleshoot something we can't see.

Comment: Good point @Unsigned. I added an example. Thanks

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Which iPad are you using, on which version of iOS, and which browser?

Comment: @Unsigned I added the infos (iPad4, iOS6) in the question for the other users. Can it be the retina screen that cause this problem with a non retina image?

Comment: iOS 6.0 or a later minor version? Are you using Safari? Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: a minor version iOS 6.1.3 to be exact

Comment: You'll probably need to post a screenshot of what you're seeing.